# nohup exiting with error 125

Tags: nohup, exit

`nohup` exits with Error 125 when trying to start a Python script in the background, yet when using wildcards, pointing to the very same file, `nohup` works.

```
    root@rpi_2:/home/pi/shortcuts# nohup -c bash 'python /home/pi/shortcuts/python/garage_topbutton_aio_pir_v2.py' > /dev/null 2>&1 &
[1] 26261
root@rpi_2:/home/pi/shortcuts#
[1]+  Exit 125                nohup -c bash 'python /home/pi/shortcuts/python/garage_topbutton_aio_pir_v2.py' > /dev/null 2>&1

root@rpi_2:/home/pi/shortcuts# ls /home/pi/shortcuts/python/garage_topbutton_aio_pir_v2.py
/home/pi/shortcuts/python/garage_topbutton_aio_pir_v2.py

root@rpi_2:/home/pi/shortcuts# nohup bash -c 'python /home/pi/shortcuts/python/*pir*v2*' > /dev/null 2>&1 &
[1] 26304

root@rpi_2:/home/pi/shortcuts# ps topbutton
USER       PID %CPU %MEM  START   TIME STAT COMMAND
root     26304  0.1  0.6  10:27   0:00 S<l  python /home/pi/shortcuts/python/garage_topbutton_aio_pir_v2.py
root@rpi_2:/home/pi/shortcuts#
```

I am curious because this never happened before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nohup` exits with error 125 when it gets an invalid option.

You don't see the error message because of your redirections (`> /dev/null 2>&1`)

```
$ nohup -c bash 'python /home/pi/shortcuts/python/garage_topbutton_aio_pir_v2.py'
nohup: invalid option -- 'c'
Try 'nohup --help' for more information.
```

So the error happens because you swapped `-c` and `bash`.

Also, you don't need to execute a shell when not using wildcards, so this is enough to execute the script:

```
nohup python /home/pi/shortcuts/python/garage_topbutton_aio_pir_v2.py > /dev/null >&1 &
```

Comment: arggglll,well never ask questions when your mind if full of other stuff.THANKS for the info :)!!